# Compiling with C.vim on Windows?

Tags: c, compilation, vim

C.Vim works, as evidenced by the commands I've been using, syntax highlighting, and template. But I use `\rc` and nothing happens. `\rr` tells me that there is no .exe, and an Everything search tells me that it's not a directory issue.

In all the resources I've read, I don't see anything that says I need to point it to a specific compiler, though I've installed Visual Studio 2010.

How do I get C.vim to compile my code? I'm a relative beginner with Vim and C.

**Edit:** I've set the Windows Environment Variable to C:/cygwin/bin where I've downloaded and installed the GCC packages, but am still getting the same error.

**Edit2:** I've downloaded Msys and Mingw as well. I tried setting up Eclipse as well, following the instructions [here](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3au6xemfJ1iJwJ%3amax.berger.name/howto/cdt/cdt.pdf+%22Launch+Failed.+Binary+not+found.%22+eclipse+windows&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESjJKWaWehmyyt0OqLrQgrFfjY-x07qnd_SkK2ANUlRnnBc7fpxH8KzbGeBKb07gGldjCPkgpT3MV4dY3FbW5uz_LeSxKduyWPMo577W3KpdTJRDWj5UxrKqsV0rIHOw7yJ6PyDQ&sig=AHIEtbR6avknW14UoX3b2QWjshPzawpAEQ). Running make from the command line tells me that GNU Make 3.81 is running. Running `:make` in Vim tells me:

```
shell returned 2
(1 of 1) : make *** No targets specified and no makefile found
```

Trying Eclipse, I get another make error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `all'; Stop.
```

**Edit3:** I got Code::Blocks running, which is what I used to run. (It's been a while since I programmed, and even then I was a beginner.) I didn't really have to configure it at all, though I would still prefer to use Vim, so help is still much appreciated.

**Edit4:** running `make vimFirst` (vimFirst.c is my file) compiles! Running the program with `:! vimFirst.exe` works as expected. Now returning to the original question, how to do it with C.vim? It would be so much more convinient to type `\rc` and have the program compile and run, which is about 1/10 of the typing of the other method.

Comment: Is your compiler on the PATH?

Comment: I've edited the path variable - but am still getting the same error?

Comment: Are you talking about this c.vim? http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1201

Comment: pydave, it's this one: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=213

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Edit4: running make vimFirst (vimFirst.c is my file) compiles! Running the program with :! vimFirst.exe works as expected. Now returning to the original question, ... type \rc and have the program compile and run...

Check your maps for \rc and \rr:

```
:map \rc
:map \rr
```

If no mapping exists, you might have no_plugin_maps or something similar set in your vimrc.

I think you'll get what you want if you set them up like this:

```
nmap \rc :make %<<CR>
nmap \rr :! %<.exe<CR>
```

---

If you're really familiar with Visual Studio and want to use [nmake](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms930369.aspx) to build your code, you should check out the `:compiler` option. `:compiler msvc` will setup your `makeprg` and `errorformat` for nmake and Visual Studio's compiler.

I'm not sure what make is currently using to build your code, so I don't know what compiler setting you'd want.